# why not all metrics are collected ArgoCD?

Tags: argocd

I set the nodePort value for argocd-metrics and argocd-server-metrics services, but for some reason the metrics specified in the documentation are not given?
for example, the argocd_app_info metric or argocd_app_labels, there is only argocd_redis_request_duration_bucket etc are given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but all metrics began to be given only through ingress.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply all of this https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/metrics/#prometheus-operator or you can make one monitor as everything argocd have the same "app.kubernetes.io/instance: argocd" label and uses the same port called "metrics":

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name: argocd
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
     app.kubernetes.io/instance: argocd
  endpoints:
  - port: metrics
    interval: 30s
```

There are other specifics if you use for example Google Managed Prometheus, then refer to provider docs.

Also make sure kube-state-metrics is deployed ( https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/tree/main/examples/standard ).